# Angular toolbar fixed at the top

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a toolbar created by me and other components. In app.component I have something like this:

```
<app-toolbar>
</app-toolbar>

<main>
    <a [routerLink]="['/login/en']"></a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

I'd like to use "position=sticky" in order to have toolbar always at the top during the scrolling, but I can't use it because I haven't a toolbar for each component.
I'm using Angular 5.
Is there a simple way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a "template component" which contains the toolbar + a `<ng-content>`.

In the example, we suppose that you created a template with a selector like `<app-toolbar-template>`

**toolbar-template.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar-template',
  templateUrl: './toolbar-template.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toolbar-template.css']
})
export class ToolbarTemplateComponent {}
```

**toolbar-template.html**

```
<div id="toolbar">Fake toolbar</div>

<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Then, when you create a component :

- If you need the toolbar, place the content inside a `<app-toolbar-template>` tag
- If you don't need the toolbar, just place your content.
- The CSS for the toolbar management will be written in `toolbar-template.css`

**foo.component.html**

```
<!-- With the toolbar -->
<app-toolbar-template>
  <div>Content</div>
</app-toolbar-template>

OR just 

<!-- Without the toolbar -->
<div>Content</div>
```

Working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tyhqz1?file=src/app/app.component.html)